Ruby on Rails - Stimulus doesn't work with Slim-select & Tailwind (DigitalOcean App Platform)
I created an app that uses tailwind, stimulus and slim-select.
In development everything works fine, but in production my import maps break for some reason and the Asset Pipeline breaks for my Stimulus controllers.
Here is the files on the website in production:

And here are the files on development(correct):

In both cases I recieve the files: 
I tried:
  config.public_file_server.enabled = true
  config.serve_static_files = true
  config.importmap.cache_sweeper = nil
  config.asset_host = "https://test.com"

Could it be because of the cdn? I didn't seem to find anyone else that has encountered this problem.
Console log on page refresh:
INFO  --- Started GET "/" for ... at 2024-11-04 15:57:42 +0000
INFO  --- Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
INFO  --- Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 3.1ms | GC: 0.0ms)
INFO  --- Completed 200 OK in 5ms (Views: 4.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms (0 queries, 0 cached) | GC: 0.0ms)
INFO  --- Started GET "/assets/controllers/removals_controller.js" for ... at 2024-11-04 15:57:43 +0000
ERROR --- ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/controllers/removals_controller.js"):
INFO  --- Started GET "/manifest.json" for ... at 2024-11-04 15:57:45 +0000
ERROR --- ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/manifest.json"):


Please post the error that you see. What breaks?

@FrankGroeneveld Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () manifest.json I am not sure why my app can't find it, but there is the same error in development. But in development it works.

That's not the error that can cause this. Look in the console tab.

@FrankGroeneveld nothing in the console either. I edited my post and added the console log.

don't use relative imports

This fixed my issue, thanks. You can add it as an answer if you wish.
